# Function to impute missing values using mean in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

My tibble:

Data in Excel:

[image: Data in Excel]

```
impute <- read_excel(choose.files())

imp <- function(df) {
      for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
        df[is.na(df[,i]),i] <- mean(df[,i],na.rm = T)
      }
}


imp(impute)
```

> Warning messages:
>   1: In `mean.default(df[, i], na.rm = T)` :
>    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
>   2: In `mean.default(df[, i], na.rm = T)` :
>    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

The above code works fine it impute is a Data.Frame, but doesn't work if it's a Tibble. Could someone please let me know how to change the code if I were to work with Tibble.

Comment: Please copy the result of `str(yourDataframe)` to the question. I suppose there is a factor column. BTW: your function returns nothing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Images are neither code nor data unless the topic is image processing. Please click on the "r" below your question, then click on "info" and review the guidance on how to ask questions in the R tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the differences between a `data.frame` and a tibble is that data frames drop dimensions when possible by default and tibbles don't.

That is, if `x` is a data frame then `x[, i]` may or may not be a data frame, depending on `i`. If `i` is one value, then `x[, i]` will just be a vector. If `i` is a vector with multiple values then `x[, i]` will be a data frame. This can cause bugs when `i` is a variable that may or may not have multiple values, because the class may be different (with the fix being to use `x[, i, drop = FALSE]` to guarantee a `data.frame` return).

Tibbles seek to address this issue by switching the default `drop = TRUE` to `drop = FALSE`, so `x[, i]` is a tibble, regardless of whether `i` has length 1 or more.

When calculating the mean, you want `df[,i]` to be treated as a numeric vector, not a tibble with 1 column, so you need to specify it:

```
df[[i]] # This is the preferred way to extract a single column
df[, i, drop = TRUE] # this will work too (since tibble version 1.4.1)
```

This is explained in greater detail in the "Tibbles vs data.frames" section of the [Tibbles vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html).